# bash command substitution on a script that executes a background task

Tags: bash

I'd like to return the results of a script that also kicks off a background task.  The command substitution operator waits for the background task, making the call slow.  I created the following example to illustrate the problem:

```
function answer {
    sleep 5 &
    echo string
}

echo $(answer)
```

Is there a way to call a command without waiting on any background jobs it creates?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `sleep` inherits stdout and keeps it open. You can simply redirect stdout:

```
answer() {
  sleep 5 > /dev/null &
  echo "string"
}
echo "$(answer)"
```

Comment: That's what was happening.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending for the program to continue merrily along in the mean time while the function works, you can just call the function to run in the background.

```
function answer {
    sleep 5
    echo Second
}

echo $(answer) &
echo First
```

The output of which will be

```
First
Second
```

Comment: Unfortunately,  in the real-world example I need the contents of what the script returns.

Comment: I put these commands into a tmp.sh file, and then ran it using sh tmp.sh > out.txt and the output file worked just fine.