# Command substitution and undone background tasks

Tags: bash, command-substitution

Is there a way to force command substitution to exit leaving baground task undone?

Example:

```
cat test.sh
#! /bin/bash
sleep 5 &
echo "foo bar"
```

Running it without command substitution:

```
time bash test.sh
foo bar

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.000s
```

With command substitution:

```
time echo $(bash test.sh)
foo bar

real    0m5.004s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redirect stdout and stderr for `sleep`:

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 5 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
echo "foo bar"
```

[bash command substitution on a script that executes a background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698756/bash-command-substitution-on-a-script-that-executes-a-background-task)